# Конфиг для сайта

Tags: php, config

Хочу написать фреймворк (чисто для практики), возник вопрос: а как мне хранить конфиг для сайта?
обычный массив в php-файле кажется не очень красиво. Хранить в БД тоже не вариант, т.к. данные для подключения будут лежать в этом же конфиге. Может JSON или XML? Или же yaml, как в симфони?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самые распространенные решения: `array()`, `JSON`, `XML`, `YAML`, `INI`, `TOML`

**P.S.** Мнение **субъективное**, чисто от личного опыта.

---

`array()` - Тут я подразумеваю стандартный массив, который вы не хотите использовать. Несмотря на то, что вам этот вариант не нравится, скорей всего вы к этому формату придете в итоге (т.е. например, если вы выберете `XML` вы все равно будете парсить и придете к `array()`).

**Плюсы:** *плюсы - везде, но по сравнению с остальными*: самый быстрый вариант (а это важно), довольно понятен, поддерживает иерархию, широкие возможности.

**Минусы:** для меня - нет.

**Пример:**

```
$config['ip'] = '127.0.0.1';
$config['site']['ru'] = 'stackoverflow.com';
```

---

`JSON` - Я бы сказал что годный вариант, но для конфига я бы не использовал, потому что минусы значительны.

**Плюсы:** поддерживает иерархию, распространен, поддержка в `PHP` из коробки, быстро парсится.

**Минусы:** *возможно* неудобен для редактирования, *возможно* плохая читабельность иерархических структур.

**Пример:**

```
{"ip":"127.0.0.1","site":{"ru":"stackoverflow.com"}}
```

---

`XML` - Сразу отсекаем, он хорош, но для конфига не подойдет, потому что слишком много мороки для сетапа.

**Плюсы:** поддерживает иерархию, распространен, поддержка в `PHP` из коробки.

**Минусы:** плохо редактировать, плохо читается, долго парсится (копейки, но все-же)

**Пример:**

```
<config><ip>127.0.0.1</ip><site><ru>stackoverflow.com</ru></site></config>
```

---

`YAML` - Хоть визуально кажется довольно годным вариантом, на самом деле под капотом кроется куча правил(паттернов), которые усложняют реализацию и убирают очевидную простоту. Да, это современный язык конф.файлов, поддерживает списки, много форматов, включая даты, но для конфига (на практике) такие плюхи не нужны, поэтому для нашей задачи мало подходит.

**Плюсы:** хорошо читается, поддерживает иерархию, распространен, поддержка в `PHP` из коробки, широкие возможности.

**Минусы:** плохо редактируется, долго парсится (копейки, но все-же) (дольше `XML`)

**Пример:**

```
---
ip: 127.0.0.1
site:
  ru: stackoverflow.com
```

---

`INI` - Хороший вариант, если нужны простые настройки, во многих местах используется и довольно актуален, практически нет правил(паттернов) оформления.

**Плюсы:** хорошо редактировать, хорошо читается, хорошо парсится, распространен, поддержка в `PHP` из коробки.

**Минусы:** есть проблемки с иерархиями

**Пример:**

```
ip = 127.0.0.1
[site]
ru = stackoverflow.com
```

---

`TOML` - по моему мнению, был создан как упрощенная версия `YAML`, упрощенный синтаксис (более приближенный к `INI`) позволяет лучше работать с конф.файлами.

**Плюсы:** хорошо читается, поддерживает иерархию, распространен, широкие возможности.

**Минусы:** плохо редактируется (но лучше чем `YAML`), долго парсится (копейки, но все-же) (но быстрее `YAML`), не поддерживается в `PHP` из коробки

**Пример:**

```
ip = "127.0.0.1"

[site]
ru = "stackoverflow.com"
```

---

Выбор конечно-же за вами, в нашей задаче - для конфига, я бы остановился на `array()`, либо `INI`, потому что это быстрые и удобные варианты.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше хранить, думаю, в yml. Четкая структура. Нет "открывающих" и "закрывающих" символов. Отлично отслеживается контролем версий. Просто редактировать в любом текстовом редакторе